# Created and installed deb package but when i run it it says 'command not found'

Tags: python, linux, bash, package, debian

I'm trying to turn a simple python program into a debian package for Linux.

I created a folder `/testhello`, and created `testhello/DEBIAN` and `testhello/usr`. Inside `testhello/DEBIAN` i have a control file that contains:

```
Package: testhello
Version: 0.01
Architecture: all
Maintainer: Me,me@gmail.com
Installed-Size: 2
Depends: python3
Section: extras
Priority: optional
Homepage: your homepage
Description: describe
```

Inside `testhello/usr` there's a `bin` folder, that contains `testhello.py`, a file that contains a single line, `print("hello world")`

I then successfully ran `dpkg -b testhello` and then `sudo dpkg -i testhello`.

But when i run the command `testhello` in bash i am greeted with `testhello: command not found`

What can I do?

Edit 1: When i go to /bin i can see testhello.py there.

Comment: Remove the `.py` or invoke it as `testhello.py`

Comment: I invoked it as testhello.py and it runs. I gave it permission through chmod +x but it's giving the error /usr/bin/hello.py: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `"hello"'
/usr/bin/hello.py: line 1: `print("hello")'

Answer (score 1):

Check the shebang (first line):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
print("hello world")
```

give execute permission and should work.